# 403 Forbidden and subsequently, The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project. Everything is workingm until I try to upload an image while updating or adding a new payment method. First I get a 403 error, and if I refresh the error page, I get another different error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

These errors shows up in the console as

```
1)Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function
    at
2)POST example.com/admin/deposit/gateway/manual/update/1001 403
3)GET example.com/admin/deposit/gateway/manual/update/1001 405
```

If omit the image, I do not get any error, but it is important that I add it. I have cleared the cache and all, but nothing seems to work.

Here are my Route definitions:

```php
Route::get('deposit/gateway/manual', 'ManualGatewayController@index')->name('deposit.manual.index');
Route::get('deposit/gateway/manual/new', 'ManualGatewayController@create')->name('deposit.manual.create');
Route::post('deposit/gateway/manual/new', 'ManualGatewayController@store')->name('deposit.manual.store');
Route::get('/deposit/gateway/manual/edit/{alias}', 'ManualGatewayController@edit')->name('deposit.manual.edit');
Route::post('deposit/gateway/manual/update/{id}', 'ManualGatewayController@update')->name('deposit.manual.update');
Route::post('deposit/gateway/manual/activate', 'ManualGatewayController@activate')->name('deposit.manual.activate');
Route::post('deposit/gateway/manual/deactivate', 'ManualGatewayController@deactivate')->name('deposit.manual.deactivate');
```

Controller:

```php
    public function edit($alias)
    {
        $page_title = 'New Manual Deposit Method';
        $method = Gateway::manual()->with('single_currency')->where('alias', $alias)->firstOrFail();
        return view('admin.gateway_manual.edit', compact('page_title', 'method'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $code)
    {
        $validation_rule = [
            'name'           => 'required|max: 60',
            'image'          => 'nullable|image',
            'image'          => [new FileTypeValidate(['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])],
            'rate'           => 'required|gt:0',
            'currency'       => 'required',
            'min_limit'      => 'required|gt:0',
            'max_limit'      => 'required|gte:0',
            'fixed_charge'   => 'required|gte:0',
            'percent_charge' => 'required|between:0,100',
            'instruction'    => 'required|max:64000'
        ];

        $request->validate($validation_rule);
        $method = Gateway::manual()->where('code', $code)->firstOrFail();

        $filename = $method->image;

        $path = imagePath()['gateway']['path'];
        $size = imagePath()['gateway']['size'];
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            try {
                $filename = uploadImage($request->image, $path, $size);
            } catch (\Exception $exp) {
                $notify[] = ['error', 'Image could not be uploaded.'];
                return back()->withNotify($notify);
            }
        }

        $input_form = [];
        if ($request->has('field_name')) {
            for ($a = 0; $a < count($request->field_name); $a++) {
                $arr = array();
                $arr['field_name'] = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', trim($request->field_name[$a])));
                $arr['field_level'] = trim($request->field_name[$a]);
                $arr['type'] = $request->type[$a];
                $arr['validation'] = $request->validation[$a];
                $input_form[$arr['field_name']] = $arr;
            }
        }

        $method->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'alias' => strtolower(trim(str_replace(' ','_',$request->name))),
            'image' => $filename,
            'parameters' => json_encode([]),
            'supported_currencies' => json_encode([]),
            'crypto' => 0,
            'description' => $request->instruction,
            'input_form' => $input_form,
        ]);


        $method->single_currency->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'gateway_alias' => strtolower(trim(str_replace(' ','_',$method->name))),
            'currency' => $request->currency,
            'symbol' => '',
            'min_amount' => $request->min_limit,
            'max_amount' => $request->max_limit,
            'fixed_charge' => $request->fixed_charge,
            'percent_charge' => $request->percent_charge,
            'rate' => $request->rate,
            'image' => $filename,
            'gateway_parameter' => json_encode($input_form),
        ]);

        $notify[] = ['success', $method->name . ' Manual Gateway has been updated.'];
        return redirect()->route('admin.deposit.manual.edit',[$method->alias])->withNotify($notify);
    }
```

Edit.blade.php

```php
    <form action="{{ route('admin.deposit.manual.update', $method->code) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="payment-method-item">
                            <div class="payment-method-header d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <div class="avatar-preview">
                                        <div class="profilePicPreview"
                                             style="background-image: url('{{getImage(imagePath()['gateway']['path'].'/'. $method->image)}}')"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="avatar-edit">
                                        <input type="file" name="image" class="profilePicUpload" id="image"
                                               accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>
                                        <label for="image" class="bg--primary"><i class="la la-pencil"></i></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="row mt-4">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 mb-15">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <label class="w-100 font-weight-bold">@lang('Gateway Name') <span
                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="@lang('Method Name')" name="name"
                                                       value="{{ $method->name }}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                            <div>
                                                <label class="w-100 font-weight-bold">@lang('Currency') <span
                                                        class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" name="currency" class="form-control border-radius-5"
                                                       value="{{ @$method->single_currency->currency }}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-5 col-md-12">
                                            <label class="w-100 font-weight-bold">@lang('Rate') <span
                                                    class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                            <div class="input-group has_append" style="max-width: 100%">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <div class="input-group-text">1 {{ trans($general->cur_text) }} =</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" name="rate"
                                                       value="{{ getAmount(@$method->single_currency->rate) }}"/>
                                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                                    <div class="input-group-text"><span class="currency_symbol"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="payment-method-body">
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="card border--primary mt-3">
                                            <h5 class="card-header bg--primary">@lang('Range')</h5>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                                    <label class="w-100 font-weight-bold">@lang('Minimum Amount') <span
                                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                        <div class="input-group-text">{{ trans($general->cur_text) }}</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="min_limit"
                                                           placeholder="0" value="{{ getAmount(@$method->single_currency->min_amount) }}"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <label class="w-100 font-weight-bold">@lang('Maximum Amount') <span
                                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                        <div class="input-group-text">{{ trans($general->cur_text) }}</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0"
                                                           name="max_limit" value="{{ getAmount(@$method->single_currency->max_amount) }}"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="card border--primary mt-3">
                                            <h5 class="card-header bg--primary">@lang('Charge')</h5>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                                    <label class="w-100 font-weight-bold">@lang('Fixed Charge') <span
                                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                        <div class="input-group-text">{{ trans($general->cur_text) }}</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0"
                                                           name="fixed_charge" value="{{ getAmount(@$method->single_currency->fixed_charge) }}"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <label class="w-100 font-weight-bold">@lang('Percent Charge') <span
                                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                        <div class="input-group-text">%</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0"
                                                           name="percent_charge" value="{{ getAmount(@$method->single_currency->percent_charge) }}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="card border--dark mt-3">

                                            <h5 class="card-header bg--dark">@lang('Deposit Instruction')</h5>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <textarea rows="8" class="form-control border-radius-5 nicEdit"
                                                              name="instruction">{{ @$method->description  }}</textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="card border--dark mt-3">
                                            <h5 class="card-header bg--dark  text-white">@lang('User data')
                                                <button type="button"
                                                        class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light float-right addUserData"><i
                                                        class="la la-fw la-plus"></i>@lang('Add New')
                                                </button>
                                            </h5>

                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <div class="row addedField">

                                                    @if($method->input_form != null)
                                                        @foreach($method->input_form as $k => $v)
                                                            <div class="col-md-12 user-data">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <div class="input-group mb-md-0 mb-4">
                                                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                            <input name="field_name[]" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$v->field_level}}" required placeholder="@lang('Field Name')">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-md-3 mt-md-0 mt-2">
                                                                            <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                                                                                <option value="text" @if($v->type == 'text') selected @endif> @lang('Input Text') </option>
                                                                                <option value="textarea" @if($v->type == 'textarea') selected @endif> @lang('Textarea') </option>
                                                                                <option value="file" @if($v->type == 'file') selected @endif> @lang('File upload') </option>
                                                                            </select>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-md-3 mt-md-0 mt-2">
                                                                            <select name="validation[]"
                                                                                    class="form-control">
                                                                                <option value="required" @if($v->validation == 'required') selected @endif> @lang('Required') </option>
                                                                                <option value="nullable" @if($v->validation == 'nullable') selected @endif>  @lang('Optional') </option>
                                                                            </select>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="col-md-2 mt-md-0 mt-2 text-right">
                                                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                                <button class="btn btn--danger btn-lg removeBtn w-100" type="button">
                                                                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                                                </button>
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    @endif

                                                </div>

                                            </div>


                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-block ">@lang('Save Method')</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

error_log

```
[09-Sep-2021 23:42:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/gcryjcwa/public_html\core\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gcryjcwa/public_html/index.php on line 34
[09-Sep-2021 23:42:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/gcryjcwa/public_html\core\vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in /home/gcryjcwa/public_html/index.php on line 34
[09-Sep-2021 23:43:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/gcryjcwa/public_html/core\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gcryjcwa/public_html/index.php on line 34
[09-Sep-2021 23:43:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/gcryjcwa/public_html/core\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gcryjcwa/public_html/index.php on line 34
[09-Sep-2021 23:43:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/gcryjcwa/public_html/core\vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in /home/gcryjcwa/public_html/index.php on line 34
```

I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

With high probably, you may want to run [`composer install`](https://getcomposer.org/) within that project's directory, to begin with. This will install dependencies and render the `autoloader.php`, which it cannot find. All the other error messages may be bogus (subsequent errors due to missing the `autoloader.php`).

Comment: I already did. It didn’t solve the problem.